# Cartesian product whose output is not in lexicographic ordering

Tags: python

I want do a Cartesian product between severable iterables in Python and I would like to specify the order of the iteration.

E.g. I have 3 iterables: `'AB', 'xy', '01'` in my example. When I write

```
import itertools
print list(itertools.product('AB', 'xy', '01'))
```

the output is in [lexicographic order](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
('A', 'x', '0')
('A', 'x', '1')
('A', 'y', '0')
('A', 'y', '1')
('B', 'x', '0')
('B', 'x', '1')
('B', 'y', '0')
('B', 'y', '1')
```

I would like to be able to specify that I want to first iterate on iterable 1 ( `'AB'`), then iterable 3 ( `'01'`), then iterable 2 ( `'xy'`), which would give the following output:

```
('A', 'x', '0')
('B', 'x', '0')
('A', 'x', '1')
('B', 'x', '1')
('A', 'y', '0')
('B', 'y', '0')
('A', 'y', '1')
('B', 'y', '1')
```

Is there any standard way to do it in Python? I'm OK to use Numpy.

Comment: Why don't you just pass the iterables in the order you want to iterate?

Comment: @BrenBarn The elements of each tuple have to be ordered in a certain way. I guess I could reorganize them after calling itertools.product, but that sounds to me like an unnecessary second pass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass the iterables in the order you want them to be iterated (or rather, with your terminology, the reverse order --- the first one passed will be the outermost iteration, so it will cycle "slowest").  If you must have the result tuples in a different order, just swap the results afterwards:

```
>>> [(c, a, b) for a, b, c in itertools.product('xy', '01', 'AB')]
[(u'A', u'x', u'0'),
 (u'B', u'x', u'0'),
 (u'A', u'x', u'1'),
 (u'B', u'x', u'1'),
 (u'A', u'y', u'0'),
 (u'B', u'y', u'0'),
 (u'A', u'y', u'1'),
 (u'B', u'y', u'1')]
```

Note this doesn't require any extra pass over the results: each tuple is swapped as it is generated.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realized swapping would be so easy!